# Why there exists four Z2 invariants for a three-dimensional topological insulator (TI) and one Z2 invariant for a two-dimensional TI?

Tags: topological-insulators

As Kane Mele suggested that there exist four Z2 invariants for a three-dimensional topological insulator (TI) while only one for two dimensional TI. But what is the reason for the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Please check https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5693, section 3.6 and 3.7.

Basically, you could have 6 $Z_2$ invariants in the 3D BZ, on the 6 planes $x=0, x=\pi, y=0, y=\pi, z=0, z=\pi$. However, these 6 invariants are not independent. If denote the 6 invariants as $x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1, z_0, z_1$, then $x_0 x_1 = y_0 y_1 =z_0 z_1$ because of the same form they have, which gives two constraints. Such that for 3D there are four indepedent $Z_2$ invariants in total.